# Change EditText board colour without shapes

Tags: android, android-edittext, border, background-color

I need to change my `EditText`  border colour. I know that there is a way with shapes, setting  shape with red boards as `EditText`'s   background. But I think that there must be some other and easer way. I searched but didn't found anything. So does anybody knows some other way?

Comment: use an image of an EditText with borders and set it as your EditText background..easier way..

Comment: Thanks for reply but It'll take more memory so I need other way.

Comment: you can try to override it (http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/1.5_r4/android/widget/EditText.java)

Comment: Thanks for reply barn.gumbl but tell the truth I didn't find anything usable in your link

Comment: If you meant to override EditText I have already override it, I made my own EditText class extends from EditText and I'm using it in my xml

Comment: Why do you think it'll use more memory, when the default behaviour is just this: to load an image for the background, and you'll just tell it to load a different picture than the default one!? You can use the [Android Holo Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) to generate your EditText(just chose the color, check EditText and download the package)

Answer (score 1):

Take one image with border what u like and set that image in edittext background

Comment: Thanks for reply but It'll take more memory, I'm looking for some function or anything better. Anywhere I'll up-vote you answer ;)